# Only 'else' is getting executed in the 'if else' statement in my Android app

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Whenever I run the app, and type in 4 as the answer, it's still showing incorrect (from the else statement). ( I am relatively new to Android coding, and couldn't find an exact solution online.)

Here is my code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText answer;
    ImageButton ttsBtn;
    Button submitBtn;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    TextView txt;
    int num;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        answer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        ttsBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ttsButton);
        submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        String ans = answer.getText().toString();
        if (!ans.isEmpty())
        {num = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString());}

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if(i!=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                    // To Choose language of speech
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

        ttsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newSpeech = "What is 2 multiplied by 2?";
                textToSpeech.speak(newSpeech,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        });

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (num == 4){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Answer is Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Answer is Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The value of `num` is only being changed in `onCreate`

Comment: there is no javascript in this question, because java is not javascript, not related - it even says so in the tag description of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Replace your submitBtn onclick with below code. Issue is that you are not assigning latest value of answer.

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        num = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString());
        if (num == 4){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Answer is Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Answer is Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```